# C# - CsGL invalid enumerant

Tags: c#, opengl

I was trying to follow this tutorial to make an OpenGL application on C#. http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3823/opengl-in-c/2/

Later on, I tried to make the following changes:

```
class DrawObject : OpenGLControl
{
    public override void glDraw()
    {
        GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL.glLoadIdentity();
        GL.glBegin(GL.GL_LINE);
        GL.glLineWidth(10.0f);
        GL.glVertex3f(-3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL.glVertex3f(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL.glEnd();
        GL.glFlush();
    }

    protected override void InitGLContext()
    {
        GL.glShadeModel(GL.GL_SMOOTH);
        GL.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        GL.glClearDepth(1.0f);
        GL.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_LEQUAL);
        GL.glHint(GL.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL.GL_NICEST);
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);

        Size s = Size;
        double aspect_ratio = (double)s.Width / (double)s.Height;
        GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL.glLoadIdentity();

        GL.gluPerspective(45.0f, aspect_ratio, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL.glLoadIdentity();
    }
}

public class DrawLine : Form
{
    DrawObject newObject = new DrawObject();

    public DrawLine()
    {
        Text = "Draw a line";
        newObject.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Controls.Add(newObject);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        DrawLine drawLine = new DrawLine();
        Application.Run(drawLine);
    }
}
```

For some reason, I will then get an "invalid enumerant" error, at Application.Run(drawLine).  Basically what I'm trying to do is to replace the part where it renders a dot on 3 specified vertices, with a part where it renders a line given 2 vertices. I do not know why the dot version does not throw this exception, but the line version does. I have referenced csgl.dll in my references, and added csgl.native.dll and made it to be published every time the solution is compiled (otherwise the whole thing wouldn't run at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change state inside `glBegin` and `glEnd` (that is, don't call `glLineWidth`). From the [docs](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLineWidth.xml):

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if glLineWidth is executed between 
the execution of glBegin and the corresponding execution of glEnd.
```

---

Answer from JulianLee: `glBegin` must be called with `GL_LINES`, not `GL_LINE`. See comments.

Comment: so i should add that line to InitGLContext instead?

Comment: Yes, or just before the `glBegin` call.

Comment: Sorry it still doesn't work...it looks like this now:
GL.glLineWidth(10.0f);        
GL.glBegin(GL.GL_LINE);

Comment: I've figured it out, I should be using GL_LINES, not GL_LINE. Thanks anyway Stefan